# How to program a Nucleo board (L053R8) using UART?

Tags: stm32, uart, bootloader

I went through all possible data sheets I could find did all the required things but my Nucleo still won’t be programmed with uart.

I have put boot0 on VDD pin next to it. For confirmation I also put PB2 (nboot1) on ground next to it.

I tried powering the nucleo through both the USB as well as an external supply (E5V) and switched to e5v.

I reset the controller to try programming.

I’m using an FTDI, connected the Rx, Tx to the USART1 (PA9, PA10) and Gnd from FTDI to the Gnd of Nucleo
I connected my Rx, Tx and Ground of my UART to usb (which I checked with the nucleo by programming a UART program through st link and it works)

I am using St flash which says there was no communication

and stm32 programmer says it timed out for the com port

i even checked that there was no read or write protection enabled and nboot1 option bits are correct by connecting to stm32 programmer through STlink

what am I missing?

Comment: Which exact "FTDI" you have and how exaxtly you connected it to where? Can you transmit and receive normally via PA9/PA10 but just not program? Did you connect TX to TX or TX to RX? Is the USB UART a TTL/CMOS level UART, 5V or 3v3 level UART or RS-232 level UART?

Comment: In addition to the previous comment (which is totally valid), connect FTDI TX to its own RX, see if it works at all (send something to yourself). I checked the bootloader application note AN2606, USART1 and USART2 should both work for bootoader of your MCU. The issue should be on the converter side. FT232 is known for having driver issues with fake chips, and there is no way to tell if it's fake until you try it (if you have that IC, that is). Specify the converter you use.

Comment: yes, I can transmit receive normally in a running program via the uart connected on the FTDI